# Request headers data is present multiple times and not once

Tags: angular, http, single-page-application, .net-6.0

I am working on a web app (Angular + .NET 6). I have a strange issue with calling the API (either from the app or from swagger). Both apps are contained in the same .NET solution using SPA middleware.

Whenever I want to call one of my endpoints (that were working before I create the angular app and configure my API to use it), it takes a lot of time for the request to complete, and I end up with a HTTP 500 error and this message in .NET console :

```
[webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:52432/api/client/ClientCareCategory/GetAll to https://localhost:44386/ [HPE_HEADER_OVERFLOW]
```

I looked on the response headers of that call, and I saw that the content of the headers was strange:

```
x-powered-by: Express, ASP.NET, ASP.NET, ASP.NET, ASP.NET, ASP.NET, ASP.NET, ASP.NET, ASP.NET, ASP.NET, ASP.NET, ASP.NET, ASP.NET.......
```

Note that even with a custom header configuration I also have this multiplicated content (eg: adding X-XSS-Protection or X-Content-Type-Options). I assume this is the reason of the `HPE_HEADER_OVERFLOW`. But I wasn't able to find the origin of this strange behaviour.

I tried :

- Removing my custom middlewares
- Checked the code of my middlewares
- Check my Angular app configuration
- Searched for known issues with the versions I am using (.NET 6, Angular 15, Node 18)

But I didn't manage to solve my issue.

Here is my Program.cs (I removed DbContext, services and repositories):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddCors(options => 
    options.AddPolicy("Default", policyBuilder =>
    {
        policyBuilder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader();
    })
);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.SaveToken = true;
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                builder.Configuration
                    .GetSection(ApplicationSettings.Section)
                    .GetValue<string>("JWT:Secret")))
    };
});

builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
});

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(config =>
{
    config.SwaggerDoc("Backend", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Backend", Version = "0.1"});

    config.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please enter a valid token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });

    var securityRequirement = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "Bearer"
                }
            },
            Array.Empty<string>()
        }
    };

    config.AddSecurityRequirement(securityRequirement);
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();
app.UseMiddleware<JwtMiddleware>();
app.UseMiddleware<AntiXssMiddleware>();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("Default");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();   

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/Backend/swagger.json", "Backend");
    });

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    });
}
else
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
        spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(app.Environment.ContentRootPath, "ClientApp", "dist")),
            RequestPath = ""
        };
    });
}

app.Run();
```

This is my Angular configuration :

```
------------------- package.json
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run Institut:server:dev",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
},

------------------- angular.json
"serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
        "browserTarget": "Institut:build",
        "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
    },
    "configurations": {
        "production": {
            "browserTarget": "Institut:build:production"
        },
        "development": {
            "browserTarget": "Institut:build:development"
        }
    },
    "defaultConfiguration": "development"
},

------------------- proxy.conf.json
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://localhost:44386",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Is there any issue in my configuration ? Is there anything else I can check that I didn't already ?

Let me know if you need additional information.

Thanks !

EDIT :

I also tried to start from Microsoft's .NET + Angular [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022), which works perfectly fine locally. The issue only happens when setting up SpaMiddleware.

Comment: Seems the reason of problems is your proxy.conf.json. The proxy has itself as a target that's why it re-sends a request to itself in infinite loop. Here a guy has the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75289528/hpe-header-overflow-when-i-add-spa-middleware-in-net-api. I hope it will help you to reconfigure your own app.

Comment: I tried deleting the proxy, but I end up with a 404. That I do not understand either as the url seems correct.
The other question you sent is one of mine. But I am not in the same case, as I deleted the SPA to solve it, but I finally need to use a SPA so I can't reuse my previous solution

Comment: I feel that the issue is coming from somewhere else, when I try the "working configuration", which is the template I am telling about in my edit, I should not have a message telling that "ng serve" failed. It should not call ng serve at that point, but build the angular app and use the output

Comment: @Scryper Looks like the proxy setup issue. Just curious, what port is you api running on? and is Angular app running on the default port?

Comment: They are both running on 44386 (I can call my API using that port via postman or /swagger, and the app opens on that port in my browser)

Comment: I am facing the issue again. In the meantime I first solved it by using .NET + angular official template. But it is now obsolete because I have to enable SSR for this app (based on https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices). But now I get this error back
I made more research but found nothing new
Do you have any insights ?